# The operation combins tripple and double dots notations - it requires explanation

Tags: dart

What is the magic here?

How do we get `onLeftItem` and `onRighItem` here?

And what does it mean `[...this]` and then `..sort` on that?

```
List<User> sorted() => [...this]..sort(
  (onLeftItem, onRighItem) {
    // some logik operations here
  },
);
```

Comment: `...` is the [spread operator](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#spread-operator). `..` is [cascade notation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#cascade-notation).

Comment: @mmcdon20 probaly the `this` is a list too then why to spread its elements in a new collection? is not it possible to use `this..sort(... ` instead?

Comment: it would be possible to do that yes, but I assume it copied into a new list to avoid modifying the original list.